# Modify main slide dimensions-Beamer

Tags: beamer, width, paper-size, themes, height

I'mm making a Beamer Presentation and I would like to use as much space as possible for my slides, because I want the images that will be included to be as visible as possible. More specifically I would like to reduce the spaces indicated by the red arrows in the picture

[image]

to reduce the height of the outertheme and move the logo picture to the bottom.

How is that possible?

My code is the following

```
\documentclass[slidestop,compress,mathserif,10pt,xcolor=dvipsnames]{beamer}

\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}
\usetheme{Ilmenau}
\usepackage[bars]{beamerthemetree}
\addtobeamertemplate{block begin}{}{\justifying}
\useoutertheme[subsection=true]{smoothbars}

\usepackage{ifthen}
\newboolean{doublelogo}%Double logo after a certain slide
\setboolean{doublelogo}{true}
\logo{%
  \makebox[0.99\paperwidth]{%
  \ifthenelse{\boolean{doublelogo}}{
    \includegraphics[width=0.6cm,keepaspectratio]{ntua-logo.jpg}}{}%
    \hfill%
    \includegraphics[width=0.9cm,keepaspectratio]{ntof-logo.pdf}%
    \hfill
    \includegraphics[width=0.6cm,keepaspectratio]{cern-logo.jpg}
  }%
}

\title{Title}
\author{author}
\date{}

\begin{document}
 \titlepage
\end{document}
```

Comment: Is the `paper-size` tag relevant for this question?

Answer (score 1):

**First Part**

Moving the Logos: That is simple just use `\vspace`. Adjust the `-0.3cm` according to your needs.

```
\logo{%
    \vspace*{-0.3cm}
    \makebox[0.99\paperwidth]{%
        \includegraphics[width=0.6cm,keepaspectratio]{cern_logo}
    }%
}
```

**Second Part**

In your MWE I do not see as much free space around the headline as in your picture, but in case you want to change the spacing you can redefine the headline. For example you can adjust the height `ht=2.75ex` of the box

```
\makeatletter
\setbeamertemplate{headline}
{%
    \pgfuseshading{beamer@barshade}%
    \ifbeamer@sb@subsection%
    \vskip-9.75ex%
    \else%
    \vskip-7ex%
    \fi%
    \begin{beamercolorbox}[ignorebg,ht=2.75ex,dp=3.75ex]{section in head/foot}
        \insertnavigation{\paperwidth}
    \end{beamercolorbox}%
    \ifbeamer@sb@subsection%
    \begin{beamercolorbox}[ignorebg,ht=2.125ex,dp=1.125ex,%
        leftskip=.3cm,rightskip=.3cm plus1fil]{subsection in head/foot}
        \usebeamerfont{subsection in head/foot}\insertsubsectionhead
    \end{beamercolorbox}%
    \fi%
}%
\makeatother
```

**Full Code**

```
\documentclass[slidestop,compress,mathserif,10pt,xcolor=dvipsnames]{beamer}

\usetheme{Ilmenau}
\usepackage[bars]{beamerthemetree}
\addtobeamertemplate{block begin}{}{\justifying}
\useoutertheme[subsection=true]{smoothbars}

\usepackage{ifthen}
\newboolean{doublelogo}%Double logo after a certain slide
\setboolean{doublelogo}{true}
\logo{%
    \vspace*{-0.3cm}
    \makebox[0.99\paperwidth]{%
        \includegraphics[width=0.6cm,keepaspectratio]{cern_logo}
    }%
}

\makeatletter
\setbeamertemplate{headline}
{%
    \pgfuseshading{beamer@barshade}%
    \ifbeamer@sb@subsection%
    \vskip-9.75ex%
    \else%
    \vskip-7ex%
    \fi%
    \begin{beamercolorbox}[ignorebg,ht=2.75ex,dp=3.75ex]{section in head/foot}
        \insertnavigation{\paperwidth}
    \end{beamercolorbox}%
    \ifbeamer@sb@subsection%
    \begin{beamercolorbox}[ignorebg,ht=2.125ex,dp=1.125ex,%
        leftskip=.3cm,rightskip=.3cm plus1fil]{subsection in head/foot}
        \usebeamerfont{subsection in head/foot}\insertsubsectionhead
    \end{beamercolorbox}%
    \fi%
}%
\makeatother


\title{Title}
\author{author}
\date{}

\begin{document}

    \begin{frame}
            \titlepage
    \end{frame}

    \section{test}

    \subsection{testtest}

    \begin{frame}
        test
    \end{frame}

    \begin{frame}
        test
    \end{frame} 

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer! The logo issue it seems to be solved! However the upper box is not... Instead of 2.75ex I put 10ex just to see how it works and it seems that only the letteres are moved http://imgur.com/G9PNwa9